# printing the host name from group in inventory

Tags: ansible

I have below inventory file:

```
[web]
10.0.1.0

[db]
10.0.3.0

[frontend]
10.0.5.0

[X_all:children]
web
db
frontend
```

Now in my playbook: I'm trying to print the hostname under X_all group in the name line.

```
   -  name: "Copying the output of Registry run to local machine from {{ hostvars[item]['inventory_hostname'] }}"
      become: true
      become_user: "{{ login }}"
      fetch:
        src: /tmp/DeploymentRegistry.txt
        dest: /tmp/DeploymentRegistry-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
        flat: yes
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['X_all'] }}"
```

Is it even possible to add the hostname in the name line?
I tried replacing `{{ hostvars[item]['inventory_hostname'] }}` with `inventory_hostname` but it's also not working.

Comment: are you certain the file is actually present on the remote? If you don't specify 'fail_on_missing' you might not see an error depending on your ansible version. `inventory_hostname` is the correct variable to use.

Comment: The task name is only printed once per task, regardless of the number of iterations. So in this case your variable in the task name will not work. Really only global variables will work in task names for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your requirement

> *I'm trying to print the hostname under `test` group in the name line.*

take note that the group has more than one member and therefore more than one hostname, but a list of hostnames.

```yaml
- name: Show hosts {{ groups['test'] }}
  delegate_to: localhost
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}" # will show the group member hostname(s)
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['test'] }}"
```

> *Is it even possible to add the hostname in the name line? I tried ... with `inventory_hostname` but it's also not working.*

Yes, it is.

```yaml
- name: Show host {{ inventory_hostname }}
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['test'] }}"
```

But it will print the first hostname from list only.